# How to convert from 'int' to 'string' in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

this my code for login :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
       var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                if (returnUrl != null)
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                else if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id, "Admin")) //<= Checking Role and redirecting accordingly.
                    return Redirect("~/Admin/Home/");
                else
                    return Redirect("~/User/Home");
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

but it show me this error :

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'   GoKhoda

show error in this line :

```
 else if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id, "Admin"))
```

this line for find user and role of user for redirect to page .

how can i solve this ?

**Edit**

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

**Edit(2)**

When i using the `.TosString()` show me this error .

[image]

Comment: Use "ToString()" method to convert int to string.

Comment: Try else if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id.ToString(), "Admin")), May be your TKey is a string type

Comment: what is stored in your user.Id? is it a guid or int?

Comment: @vipin i used tow . but it not work .

Comment: @Mysterio11 where i check that ?

Comment: Is there any error occurred after using .ToString()?

Comment: @vipin update question

Comment: i dont think your errors has anything to do with converting to string and occurs inside the `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync`. So first i would check if you have any values inside the `user.id` (put a break point and step through your code). Then if, `user.id` has values, can you post the code for your `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync` method.

Comment: yup put a break poin or do Response.Write(User.Id.ToString())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO your error is more than just `int` to `String` conversion, it is related to `FindByNameAsync` method. The problem occurs when `IsInRoleAsync` method requested for `UserId` property but the property doesn't exist in `ApplicationUser` class (related to Dapper mapping issue).

According to [MVC - InvalidOperationException: UserId not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246407/mvc-invalidoperationexception-userid-not-found), ensure `FindByNameAsync` to include `Id` property in `ApplicationUser` like this one (use your EF database context if you have it instead of query statement):

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    ApplicationUser result = null;
    using (var conn = await GetOpenDBConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            // note that UserId does not exist on ApplicationUser by default
            // thus we need to adjust the query statement
            var queryResults = await conn.QueryAsync<ApplicationUser>(
                "SELECT UserId AS [Id], UserName, Email FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @UserName;",
                new { UserName = userName });

            result = queryResults.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Alternatively you may try `FindByName` method instead of `FindByNameAsync` there.

Regarding the `await` usage error, the exception explains that only one async operation allowed at a time in given context (see [Multi-async in Entity Framework 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628792/multi-async-in-entity-framework-6)), hence you need to move `await` outside if-condition or create a new context before executing second `await`:

```
var isInRole = await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id.ToString(), "Admin");

// inside switch...case
if (returnUrl != null)
     return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
else if (isInRole) //<= Checking Role and redirecting accordingly.
     return Redirect("~/Admin/Home/");
else
     return Redirect("~/User/Home");
```

or change to `IsInRole` if it still throwing exception:

```
if (returnUrl != null)
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
else if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id.ToString(), "Admin")) //<= Checking Role and redirecting accordingly.
    return Redirect("~/Admin/Home/");
else
    return Redirect("~/User/Home");
```

This may or may not solve your entire issue, but may explain what should you do to handle async-related issues.

Related problems:

[MVC InvalidOperationException adding role to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639960/mvc-invalidoperationexception-adding-role-to-user)

[Manually Map column names with class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902674/manually-map-column-names-with-class-properties)

[Entity framework async issues context or query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763732/entity-framework-async-issues-context-or-query)